# mode rewrite function in .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, mode

Hom many times can I use mode_rewrite function and rule in .htaccess file?
like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /public_html
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ /game.php?game_name=$1
```

Comment: As many as you want. Impartant: place each rule on its own line.

Comment: But keep in mind for each that no rule will conflict with the other one otherwise infinite loop may be generated or other error occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use as many as you like, as long as you add them on newlines. Make sure your rules are not getting into a conflict though.

Some information about parameters you can use:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html

You can test your .htaccess with this website:
http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: Can you please give me at least an example concerned to my question(double rewrite rule)! I tried to do that. But it's not reponding...